# Populate subdocument array field with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know this question has been asked before, but after hours of research I have tried several ways to solve my problem without success.

### Schema

```
    const ValuationsSchema = new Schema(
      {
        value: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5 },
        author: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          refPath: "fromModel",
          required: true,
        },
        fromModel: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          enum: ["usertype1", "usertype2", "usertype3"],
          trim: true,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    const UserSchema = new Schema(
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        valuations: [ValuationsSchema],
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
```

### What am I trying to do

I am trying to populate the `author` field of `ValuationsSchema`, in the `valuations` array of a `user`.

### Sample data

Result expected

```
{
  _id: 5f1ef9f6039fea10c437939c,
  name: 'Jose Maria',
  createdAt: 2020-07-27T15:59:50.529Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z,
  valuations: [
    {
      _id: 5f258b973c0ac544869c0434,
      value: 5,
      author: Object,
      fromModel: 'particular',
      createdAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z
    }
  ]
}
```

Result gotten

```
{
  _id: 5f1ef9f6039fea10c437939c,
  name: 'Jose Maria',
  createdAt: 2020-07-27T15:59:50.529Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z,
  valuations: [
    {
      _id: 5f258b973c0ac544869c0434,
      value: 5,
      author: 5f1edaa83ce7cf44a2bd8a9a,
      fromModel: 'particular',
      createdAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-08-01T15:34:47.414Z
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Already tried solutions

At the moment I manually populated the field, but as it is a good practice, I am trying to use the API when possible.

As far as I am concerned executing this should get the job done, but it doesn't.

```
    await user.populate("valuations.author").execPopulate();
```

Also tried this without luck:

```
    await user.populate({
                        path: "valuations",
                        populate: {
                          path: "author",
                        },
                      }).execPopulate();
```

Tried the [deepPopulate package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate) too, but yet same result.

Comment: @turivishal added the sample data! let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: @turivishal I expect the user document associated with the object ID that it is stored in that field.

Comment: @turivishal I tried and I got this error `Schema hasn't been registered for model \"fromModel\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)` 
I need to use refPath as it is a [dynamic reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) to 3 possible user models I have defined `["usertype1", "usertype2", "usertype3"],`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219053/discussion-between-turivishal-and-raul-mabe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `refPath` should be from parent level `valuations.fromModel`,

- Change it in your schema,

```
author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: "valuations.fromModel",
    required: true,
}
```

- Single document wise population,

```
let user = await User.find();
let user1 = await user[0].populate("valuations.author").execPopulate();
```

- All documents population

```
let users = await User.find().populate("valuations.author").execPopulate();
```

> **Note:** There is a bug [#6913](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6913) in mongoose version 5.2.9, `refPath` not working in nested arrays, Make sure you have installed latest version.